# How to get FireWire details with WMI?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, wmi, firewire

I have to get the firewire details from user PC before installing the application, I'm able to get the Win32_1394Controller Object using WMI query, so I get most of the details.

But my main objective is to get the what firewire connector user installed on their machine. Like is it a 4,6 or 9 pin connector?

Is there any possibility I can get these details?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. I hand-built my machine; how would WMI guess what ports exist? The difference between 4 and 6 pin connectors is a pair of power pins.